# writing module to .bc bitcode file

Tags: file-io, llvm

i've assumed that dumping a .bc file from a module was a trivial operation, but now,
first time i have to actually do it from code, for the life of me i
can't find one missing step in the process:

```
static void WriteModule ( const Module *  M, BitstreamWriter &  Stream )
```

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BitcodeWriter_8cpp.html#a828cec7a8fed9d232556420efef7ae89

to write that module, first i need a BistreamWriter

```
BitstreamWriter::BitstreamWriter (SmallVectorImpl< char > &O)
```

http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1BitstreamWriter.html

and for a BitstreamWriter i need a SmallVectorImpl. But, what next?
Should i write the content of the SmallVectorImpl byte by byte on a
file handler myself? is there a llvm api for this? do i need something
else?

Comment: [C api](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/BitWriter_8cpp_source.html) provides a simple way to do that. Use it directly or see how it works and do the same.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `WriteModule` function is **static** within `lib/Bitcode/Writer/BitcodeWriter.cpp`, which means it's not there for outside consumption (you can't even access it).

The same file has another function, however, called `WriteBitcodeToFile`, with this interface:

```
/// WriteBitcodeToFile - Write the specified module to the specified output
/// stream.
void llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(const Module *M, raw_ostream &Out);
```

I can't imagine a more convenient interface. The header file declaring it is `./include/llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h`, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I use following code :

```
std::error_code EC;
llvm::raw_fd_ostream OS("module", EC, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
WriteBitcodeToFile(pBiFModule, OS);
OS.flush();
```

and then disassemble using llvm-dis.