# How to save IR to a file and build it to an executable file?

Tags: build, llvm, llvm-ir

Now I use clang build my .c file to .s file. And I have used the llvm API modify the IR. However, now I can't save my modified IR to a file. I want to use "LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile", but I can't find the struct of "LLVMOpaqueModule"; I want to use "WriteBitcodeToFile", it always show me "type mismatch". And I also want to know how to build an IR file to a executable file.

Next are two methods I use to save a module:

1、First use WriteBitcodeToFile

```
bool unbuffered = false; 
llvm::raw_ostream ro(unbuffered); 
WriteBitcodeToFile(m, ro);
```

2、Second use LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile

```
const char *Path = "hello2.s"; 
int ans = LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(m, Path);
```

note: m is a point of Module instance

Comment: The correct function to use is indeed `WriteBitcodeToFile` from `Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h`. If you fail using it, you should provide the code you are trying to compile in this question.

Comment: Yes,Follow is the prototype of WriteBitcodeToFilevoid: WriteBitcodeToFile(const Module *M, raw_ostream &Out);

Comment: Yes,Follow is the prototype of WriteBitcodeToFilevoid: WriteBitcodeToFile(const Module *M, raw_ostream &Out); when I init a raw_stream, I can't afford a type match  parameter. which has a defaulted parameter.

Comment: Next are two methods I use to save a module:                     bool unbuffered = false;
llvm::raw_ostream ro(unbuffered);     
WriteBitcodeToFile(m, ro);
  
const char *Path = "hello2.s";
int ans = LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(m, Path);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For saving the IR into a file, see the answer to this question: [writing module to .bc bitcode file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903686/writing-module-to-bc-bitcode-file)
2. For compiling IR to an object file, look at the `llc` tool and follow what its `main` function does.

Comment: Thanks, But when I init an instance of raw_ostream which is a parameter of WriteBitcodeToFile, I can't do it.Neither prompt no parameter ,nor type mismatch.

Comment: And another I remember that llc just make the IR become assembly, we just can allocate the platform.

Comment: Next are two methods I use to save a module:                     bool unbuffered = false;
llvm::raw_ostream ro(unbuffered);     
WriteBitcodeToFile(m, ro);
  
const char *Path = "hello2.s";
int ans = LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile(m, Path);

Comment: @KunLee: could you edit your question to provide this additional information in a structured, well-formatted and well-expressed manner? That would greatly increase the chances of your question being answered

Comment: @KunLee: do you want to write to a file? Then use `raw_fd_ostream`. If you just want to write to stdout, use `outs()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these functions in `llvm-c/TargetMachine.h`:

```
/** Emits an asm or object file for the given module to the filename. This
  wraps several c++ only classes (among them a file stream). Returns any
  error in ErrorMessage. Use LLVMDisposeMessage to dispose the message. */
LLVMBool LLVMTargetMachineEmitToFile(LLVMTargetMachineRef T, LLVMModuleRef M,
  char *Filename, LLVMCodeGenFileType codegen, char **ErrorMessage);

/** Compile the LLVM IR stored in \p M and store the result in \p OutMemBuf. */
LLVMBool LLVMTargetMachineEmitToMemoryBuffer(LLVMTargetMachineRef T, LLVMModuleRef M,
  LLVMCodeGenFileType codegen, char** ErrorMessage, LLVMMemoryBufferRef *OutMemBuf);
```

See also [How to generate machine code with llvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13464259/how-to-generate-machine-code-with-llvm/33900895#33900895)

Answer (score 0):

for writing llvm bitcode to file what I do is :

```
std::error_code EC;
llvm::raw_fd_ostream OS("module", EC, llvm::sys::fs::F_None);
WriteBitcodeToFile(pBiFModule, OS);
OS.flush();
```

and then disassemble using llvm-dis.