# How to dump llvm module to .ll file

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I see from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13928250/9614249) there is a way to dump a module to bitcode (.bc), but I would like to dump the IR to a .ll file so that I can view the IR.

I know `llvm-dis` can convert .bc to .ll but in my case it does not work. 
I have written some passes that transform the module in a way that `llvm-dis` fails to convert the bitcode to IR.

Is there an API similar to `LLVMWriteBitcodeToFile` that lets me dump a module to IR directly?

Comment: [print()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a8ee5166cba8576e41617fc96aec1fb85)?

Comment: @arnt That works perfectly and now I feel dumb.

Comment: Feeling dumb is what I do nine to five ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [arnt's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60213911/how-to-dump-llvm-module-to-ll-file#comment106509253_60213911), just use [`llvm::Module::print()`](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#a8ee5166cba8576e41617fc96aec1fb85)

Comment: I use `llvmmodule->print(ostream, nullptr);` but why my llvm::Module only prints `source_filename` but nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `opt` to do that.
e.g.,

`opt -S test.bc -o test.ll`

Comment: This fails for the same reasons that `llvm-dis` does not work.