# Emit the llvm-ir bytecode from my llvm pass

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

Is there anyway to emit the llvm-ir bytecode from inside my pass, into a file? I want the same format that I am getting by using the opt tool, so I can pass this file to the opt later.

Comment: I believe the LLVM development mail list is a more appropriate place for this question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904440/dump-ir-after-each-llvm-optimization-each-pass-both-llvm-ir-passes-and-backen or http://clang.llvm.org/hacking.html#irgen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a module in the textual representation (which `opt` can parse just file) to stdout, use `Module::dump()`. To save it to a file, use `Module::print` (and just pass null as the 2nd argument). [To dump it to a bitcode file, use `llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903686/writing-module-to-bc-bitcode-file).

Comment: So I guess I will do something like : std::string errorMessage = ""; 
raw_fd_ostream file("file.txt", errorMessage); 
module->print(file, NULL); 
file.close();